Jacobian chain rule equation: proving an identity.
I have the following problem which I am unable to solve expanding out. It would be kind if someone can provide me some pointers as to how to solve the problem.
if
$$ x = f(u,v,w), y=g(u,v,w), z=h(u,v,w)$$
prove that
$$ \frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(u,v,w)} . \frac{\partial(u,v,w)}{\partial(x,y,w)} =1$$
when $$ \frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(u,v,w)} \neq 0 $$
I tried to expand the determinant (using the definition of the jacobian) but the algebra did not go any where.
It would be kind of someone to help out, thanks in advance.

Begin with the definition of the Jacobian, and matrix multiplication.
$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\partial (x,y,z)}{\partial (u,v,w)}\cdot\dfrac{\partial (u,v,w)}{\partial (x,y,z)} &= \begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u}&\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u}&\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}\\\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial v}&\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial v}&\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial v}\\\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial w}&\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial w}&\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial w}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}&\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}&\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x}\\\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}&\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}&\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial y}\\\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial z}&\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial z}&\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial z}\end{bmatrix} \\[2ex]&= \sum\limits_{\chi\in\{x,y,z\}}\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial \chi}{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \chi}&\dfrac{\partial\chi}{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial\chi}&\dfrac{\partial\chi}{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial\chi}\\\dfrac{\partial \chi}{\partial v}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \chi}&\dfrac{\partial\chi}{\partial v}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial\chi}&\dfrac{\partial\chi}{\partial v}\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial\chi}\\\dfrac{\partial \chi}{\partial w}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \chi}&\dfrac{\partial\chi}{\partial w}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial\chi}&\dfrac{\partial\chi}{\partial w}\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial\chi}\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$
Next apply the chain rule.
$$\begin{align}{}\\[4ex]{}\end{align}$$
And thus conclude that the product of these Jacobian Martices is the 3rd dimentional Identity Matix.  $$\dfrac{\partial (x,y,z)}{\partial (u,v,w)}\cdot\dfrac{\partial (u,v,w)}{\partial (x,y,z)} = \mathbf I_{3}$$

And if you want the product of absolute determinants of Jacobian matrices, just use the fact $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$, and therefore show:
$$\begin{align}\lvert\det(A)\rvert\,\lvert\det(B)\rvert &= \lvert\det(A)\det(B)\rvert\\&=\lvert\det(AB)\rvert
\\[2ex]\begin{Vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial (x,y,z)}{\partial (u,v,w)}\end{Vmatrix}\cdot\begin{Vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial (u,v,w)}{\partial (x,y,z)}\end{Vmatrix} &= 1\end{align}$$
$\blacksquare$
